# Java ArrayDeque Remove & Poll Methods Error

Tags: java, debugging, methods, arraydeque

currently i'm writing the implementation of an ArrayDeque. I'm working on my pollFirst, pollLast, removeFirst, and removeLast methods. I'm not entirely sure if my methods I've written are correct or not. I wrote a driver to test out these methods and I'm not sure if the output is correct.

The driver can be located here: https://pastebin.com/bH0D78jG

Here are the following methods:

pollFirst:

```
T result = (T) deque[head]; // Element is null if deque empty
    if (result == null)
        return null;
    deque[head] = null;     // Must null out slot
    head = (head + 1) & (deque.length - 1);
    return result;
```

pollLast:

```
    int t = (tail - 1) & (deque.length - 1);
    T result = (T) deque[t];
    if (result == null)
        return null;
    deque[t] = null;
    tail = t;
    return result;
```

removeFirst

```
    T x = pollFirst();
    if (x == null)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    return x;
```

removeLast

```
    T x = pollLast();
    if (x == null)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    return x;
```

[this is a picture of the sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAX3m.png)

the thing i'm most concerned with are the methods and how it's outputting the array after the pollFirst and pollLast. Shouldn't there be a null at each end of the deque?

Comment: Please post the whole class, not just the method bodies. For example, the code `& (deque.length - 1)` could be fine, or it could be wrong, depending on whether `deque.length` is a power of 2; but I can't check this from what you've shown.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ckf5iWbv here you go, here's the entire class :)

Comment: I will take a look, but it's better if you edit your question - it makes the question and answer page more useful for others who may have a similar problem.

Comment: Since the class is quite long, it would also help if you reduced it to a minimal example - a full class, but just the parts that are needed to demonstrate the bug.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `pollLast` method. In the `peekLast` method, you use `tail` as the index of the last element in the deque, but in the `pollLast` method you use `tail - 1` as the index of this element. This means you are removing (and nulling out) the second-from-last element instead of the last one.

To fix the bug, change the line `T result = (T) deque[t];` to be `T result = (T) deque[tail];`.